# Why isn't scrolling working in my jQuery UI sortable?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, scroll, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm having problems using the sortable function of jQuery UI. The scroll doesn't seem to work.

If the second list ( lists are created on the table rows in a tbody and each tbody is connect ) isn't visible I want it to be possible to scroll towards it for dropping my table row.

This is my HTML set up:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <table class="treeleerling">
                    <tbody class="oder0">

                        <tr class="suborder0">

                        </tr>
                        <tr class="sub1order">

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <table class="treeleerling">
                    <tbody class="oder1">

                        <tr class="suborder0">

                        </tr>

                        <tr class="suborder1">

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#left tbody").sortable({
            connectWith : '#left tbody',
            scroll : true,
            scrollSensitivity: 40,
    });
});
```

The sorting works fine, but the scrolling doesnt.. I'm doing something wrong or what?

**Update :
I refactored the code to use only listitems in a list instead of table rows in a table body. Same problem still occurs**

Answer (score 16):

This may not apply to your case, but I thought I would post my solution to a scolling problem with jQuery sortable that I was having. I'm not using a scrolling div. To get scrolling to work, I had to remove this line from my stylesheet:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden; /* this line kept page scrolling from working */
}
```

I also set the sortable 'containment' option to 'document' (which kept the item from being dragged left/right off the page, which is also what I needed).

Comment: As suggested by Craig,setting a CSS overflow property on the body element can stop the sortable's scroll from functioning. Though in my case it was overflow-y, not overflow-x that was doing the damage.

Answer (score 5):

I just stumbled upon this. Might be too late for you but for any future visitors:

Had this problem and I had to delete the following line out of my css:

```
#sortable{overflow: auto;} /*delete this */
```

So I guess any kind of overflow assigned to the sortable could be the problem.

Comment: Worked for me too. I had to remove .table-responsive {overflow-x: auto} added by Bootstrap 3 to fix this issue.

Comment: Also worked for me ... had to remove `div#wrapper { overflow: auto; }` and now it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot detect any error in your code due to my limited understanding of the jQuery UI library. BTW, where is the code for scrolling down to the div of destination?

Here is another way to walk around this issue, use another jQuery plugin : [ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo), instead.

To use it is simple, once the plugin is loaded, use code as this:

```
$.scrollTo('#your_target_element_id');
```

I have been using it in my projects, and it seems still okay with jQuery 1.4.2

Hope this helps :)

Comment: though I really like the scrollTo plugin, I shouldn't be using it..
The UI doc clearly states that it should scroll.. Why doesn't it.. :(

Comment: Now I read somewhere that the sortable function / plugin relies on the selector to be a list with listitems init. I managed to refactor my code to uses only lists and listitems, but I still does not work..

Comment: I just tested my previous statement and it is not true. The markup as provided in the question worked in a testing env.

Comment: just a guess, which browser are you using ? have you try other browsers? I was using jQuery UI last year but when I upgraded my browser to firefox 3.6, little pieces seems not right... I wonder if this one of the consistency issues in the library - then you really cannot do much about it :(